# Spring boot When running embended tomcat always use a extrange port

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, erlang

Konnichiwa (Hello).

I am following a tutorial about microservices in order to combine this with my Erlang data generator, So I have created a basic program with Spring-Boot (Java) but everytime I run the application I don't know why my tomcat is running in a weird port number.

http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2015/04/10/building-microservices-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-oss-part-1/

Maybe folks you can helpme.
Arigatou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not showing a weird port, this is a random port, maybe you have this configured in your `resources/application.properties` or `resources/application.yml` file.

```
server.port=0
```

or

```
server:
  port: 0
```

So you should replace **0**, because this means (run my server in a random auto-generated port number) and replace this for the port number you want.

Regards.

Comment: Let me try! Thank you.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the Spring Boot reference guide explaining what value 0 does. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-user-a-random-unassigned-http-port